# C++: How to print the dot11Bssid from a WLAN_BSS_ENTRY?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having a problem printing (printf) the dot11Bssid (which is a [DOT11_MAC_ADDRESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/NativeWiFi/dot11-mac-address-type) type). The address is contained within a [WLAN_BSS_ENTRY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wlanapi/ns-wlanapi-_wlan_bss_entry), which is contained within a collection returned from [WlanGetNetworkBssList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlangetnetworkbsslist).

When I attempt to print it, it looks like it's just an incremental count and not the actual value for the BSSID - but I cannot figure out why. Everything else prints as it should.

```
    if (WlanGetNetworkBssList(hWlan, &guidInterface, NULL, dot11_BSS_type_infrastructure, NULL, NULL, ppWlanBssList) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // De-reference seems to be required here to access the object returned from the call.
        PWLAN_BSS_LIST pWLanBssList = (*ppWlanBssList);
        for (unsigned int t = 0; t < pWLanBssList->dwNumberOfItems; t++)
        {
            printf("\nSSID: %s\t", pWLanBssList->wlanBssEntries[t].dot11Ssid.ucSSID);
            printf("\tBSSID: %x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x\t", pWLanBssList->wlanBssEntries[t].dot11Bssid);
            printf("\tSignal Strength: %d dbm", pWLanBssList->wlanBssEntries[t].lRssi);
        }
    }
```

This is the output:

```
SSID: [REDACTED]  BSSID: 1ef7d580:fffffd7f:c12cdd50:0:0:c12ce248  Signal Strength: -60 dbm
SSID: [REDACTED]  BSSID: 1ef7d6e8:fffffd7f:c12cdd50:0:0:c12ce248  Signal Strength: -80 dbm
SSID: [REDACTED]  BSSID: 1ef7d850:fffffd7f:c12cdd50:0:0:c12ce248  Signal Strength: -79 dbm
SSID: [REDACTED]  BSSID: 1ef7d9b8:fffffd7f:c12cdd50:0:0:c12ce248  Signal Strength: -85 dbm
SSID: [REDACTED]  BSSID: 1ef7db20:fffffd7f:c12cdd50:0:0:c12ce248  Signal Strength: -94 dbm
```

Also, it looks like the bytes are reversed (judging by the later characters being consistently the same - although, they should all be different) but given that the first group looks like an incremental count, I obviously can't trust any of the data anyway.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong, here? Do I have to print each UCHAR, indexing by character place (e.g.: dot11Bssid[0]) and not the whole object at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes print each byte of the BSSID (same format as MAC address) separately and padded with leading 0 if necessary.

```
printf("MAC address of BSS: ");
sprintf(mac, "%02x-%02x-%02x-%02x-%02x-%02x", 
                    pWlanBssEntry->dot11Bssid[0],
                    pWlanBssEntry->dot11Bssid[1],
                    pWlanBssEntry->dot11Bssid[2],
                    pWlanBssEntry->dot11Bssid[3],
                    pWlanBssEntry->dot11Bssid[4],
                    pWlanBssEntry->dot11Bssid[5]);
printf(" %s\n", mac);
```

From
https://github.com/Shouqun/geolocation/blob/master/src/geolocation_win.c

Comment: Thanks, @malhal! Had to modify it to use the safe version (sprintf_s) and it works. Tried to upvote your answer but something about it not counting was displayed.


`    char mac [200];
    sprintf_s(mac, 200, "%02x-%02x-%02x-%02x-%02x-%02x",
     pWLanBssList->wlanBssEntries[t].dot11Bssid[0],
     pWLanBssList->wlanBssEntries[t].dot11Bssid[1],
     pWLanBssList->wlanBssEntries[t].dot11Bssid[2],
     pWLanBssList->wlanBssEntries[t].dot11Bssid[3],
     pWLanBssList->wlanBssEntries[t].dot11Bssid[4],
     pWLanBssList->wlanBssEntries[t].dot11Bssid[5]);
    printf(" %s", mac);`